# An API request from my app has been blocked but still works from a browser

Tags: api, curl

The API request "https://www.vattenfall.se/api/price/spot/pricearea/2022-02-09/2022-02-15/SN3" works from a browser but not when using:
"curl -i -X GET [https://www.vattenfall.se/api/price/spot/pricearea/2022-02-09/2022-02-15/SN3"](https://www.vattenfall.se/api/price/spot/pricearea/2022-02-09/2022-02-15/SN3%22)

It work some days ago but now suddenly it is blocked.

It would be great if there is anyone that can give me some clues on what's wrong here and if there is a solution.

Comment: dumb idea from me but maybe its CORS?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, fact is that I have made an app in delphi using mormot:s http-client to send the api-request which has been working in a year but now it stopped. I have never tried curl before on this URL but when this suddenly stopped I tested both browser and curl. Browser works but not curl. Please test it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this api is looking for user-agent. Try this.

````
curl -i -X GET https://www.vattenfall.se/api/price/spot/pricearea/2022-02-09/2022-02-15/SN3 --header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'```
````

Comment: Super! :-) That made my day!